# Javascript function: dynamically created div layout issue

Tags: javascript, css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/3Sd4W/

Reference: The above js fiddle provided by [**greener**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967082/1195891).

If the new Entry Button is clicked, there is an layout issue for that new added object.

The text box style is:

```
file.setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 60px;");
```

But I want the text box to be in the middle and not at the bottom. I tried myself but it doesn't works for me. Anybody could help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is extremely complicated to read, so this may help:

HTML:

```
<form name="addpoll">

<div id="choices">


</div>
<input id="addchoice" type="button" value="Add New Entry">

</form>
```

JS:

```
function addnewDiv(counterAppended) {
    counterAppended = parseInt(counterAppended) + 1;
    var text = document.createElement("div");
    text.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" class="choicecount" name="choicecount" id="choicecount" value="' + counterAppended + '">\
<input type="file" name="choiceimg' + counterAppended + '" value ="Select"  onchange="readURL(this)" style="display:none;">\
<div>\
<div style="width:400px;height:85px;">\
<div id="imgbg" style="float:left;width: 110px;height: 80px;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #CCC;">\
<input type="button" onclick="HandFileButtonClick();"  value="Browse" id="firstremove" style="margin-top: 30px;" class="addmultiple">\
</div>\
<div style="float:right;margin-top: 30px;">\
<input type=text name="choicename' + counterAppended + '" id="firstremove2">\
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" id="firstremove3" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; border: 0px; background: none; text-decoration: underline;">\
</div>\
</div>\
<img src="#" name="viewimg' + counterAppended + '" class="addmultiple" id="viewimg' + counterAppended + '" height="70px" width="85px" style="display:none"/>\
<br>\
</div>\
<span id="file"></span>';
    text.id = 'choice' + counterAppended;
    document.getElementById("choices").appendChild(text);
    document.getElementsByClassName("remove")[document.getElementsByClassName("remove").length - 1].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    });
}

function HandFileButtonClick() {
    document.addpoll.choiceimg1.click();
}

function HandleFileButtonClick(val) {
    var ss = val.name;
    document.forms["addpoll"]
    var n = ss.split("choiceimgs");
    document.forms["addpoll"]["choiceimg" + n[1]].click();
}
document.getElementById("addchoice").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var choicecounts = document.getElementsByClassName('choicecount');
    addnewDiv(choicecounts[choicecounts.length - 1].value);
});

addnewDiv(0);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99vhF/1/

Comment: This is a very great job. Useful coding but I cant integrate into my coding.

Answer (score 1):

The first row uses a wrapper `div` for the input field with a style attribute containing `float: right`. The generated row (after clicking 'add new entry' button) does not have a div wrapper with the same attribute around the input.

Comment: How to add div for that set of elements

Answer (score 0):

You add elements to incorrect nodes. Review you "add" part. All of variables take "file" element. It looks odd:

```
var addfile = document.getElementById("file");

var view = document.getElementById("file");
var remove1 = document.getElementById("file");
var br2 = document.getElementById("file");
var textf1 = document.getElementById("file");
var myimgdiv = document.getElementById("file");
```